# Accessing response headers in responseError method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a HttpInterceptor to process authorization headers in requests made to a rest api. The idea is that the authorization header gets appended in the interceptor's request method, and authorization failures are catched by responseError.

In some cases I need to resend the request with a new authorization header, based on what the server replied in the WWW-Authenticate header. I can't figure out how to access that header in the responseError method.

To explain in code:

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    'request': function(config) {
      // do something on success
      return config;
    },
   'requestError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },
    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
        // How can I access the WWW-Authenticate header from the response here?
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: There should be a headers function in `rejection` object, that can get you header with rejection.headers('headername')

Comment: @Chandermani There is, but for some reason that only gives me Content-Type and Cache-Control. From Chrome's dev console I can see though that the WWW-Authenticate header is there too. `rejection.headers('WWW-Authenticate')` returns null.

Answer (score 1):

[Chandermani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361151/chandermani) was correct in his comment about `rejection.headers()`. The actual problem was in the server's `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, that didn't include WWW-Authenticate. Adding that fixed the problem.